# How to get an enum instance based on constructor value, and cast generically?

Tags: java, generics, enums

All my enums extend implement an interface and have one arg constructor/displayValue:

```
public enum TCType implements CustomEnum{
    Hospital("Hospital"),
    AmbulatoryCenter("Ambulatory Center"),
    IndependentLaboratory("Independent Lab");

    private final String displayValue;
    private TCType(String value) {
        displayValue = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String getDisplayValue() {
        return displayValue;
    }
}
```

This is the interface:
I also have a default method find(): input: "Ambulatory Center" return: TCType.AmbulatoryCenter

```
public interface CustomEnum{
    default String getDisplayValue(){
        return name();
    }
    String name();
}
```

**How do I get TCType.AmbulatoryCenter in valueObj?**

Code: A generic setter method using reflection - that should work for any enums that implement CustomEnum

```
if (columnMethod.columnType.isEnum()) {// here columnMethod.columnType is TCType.
    String strVal = resultSet.getString(columnName); // strVal = "Ambulatory Center"
    if (strVal != null) {
    // I expect valueObj should be TCType.AmbulatoryCenter , however I get IllegalArugmentException
    valueObj = Enum.valueOf((Class<Enum>) columnMethod.columnType, strVal);
        columnMethod.method.invoke(obj, valueObj);

    }
}
```

EDIT:
Thanks yshavit

I moved the find method to enum util.

```
class EnumUtil {

    static CustomEnum find(String enumTypeClassName, String enumDisplayValue){
        try{
            Class clazz = Class.forName(enumTypeClassName);//"constants.AccountType"
            return find(clazz, enumDisplayValue);
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw new CoraException("Error casting ModelConstant type:" + enumTypeClassName + ", dispVal="+enumDisplayValue, e);
        }

    }
    static <T extends Enum & CustomEnum> CustomEnum find(Class<T> clazz, String enumDisplayValue) {
        for (T elem : clazz.getEnumConstants()) {
            if (elem.getDisplayValue().equals(enumDisplayValue)) {
                return (CustomEnum)elem;
            }
        }
        throw new NoSuchElementException("class="+clazz.getCanonicalName()+ ",displayVal=" +enumDisplayValue);
    }
}
```

So the client code becomes:

```
if (columnMethod.columnType.isEnum() &&  CustomEnum.class.isAssignableFrom(columnMethod.columnType)) {

            String s = resultSet.getString(columnName);
            if (s != null) {
                Object enumVal = EnumUtil.find(columnMethod.columnType.getTypeName(), s);
                columnMethod.method.invoke(obj,enumVal);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Shouldn't `TCType` implement `CustomEnums<TCType>`?

Comment: You are right, typo miss, corrected in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of [erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), the specific type of `T` isn't known at runtime. The standard solution is to pass in an instance of `Class<T>`, either to the `find` method or to the `CustomEnums` constructor if it were a class. If we do the former, it'd be something like this:

```
T find(String name, Class<T> clazz) {
    for (T elem : clazz.getEnumConstants()) {
        if (elem.name().equals(name)) {
            return elem;
        }
    }
    throw new NoSuchElementException(name); // or whatever
}
```

In Java 8, you can shorten this even further:

```
T find(String name, Class<T> clazz) {
    return Stream.of(clazz.getEnumConstants())
        .filter(name::equals)) // note, will NPE if name == null
        .findFirst()
        .get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The string parameter to [`Enum.valueOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String-) is the declared name of the enum. You are instead passing the description: "Ambulatory Center" instead of "AmbulatoryCenter".

You need to use your `find` method instead of `valueOf`.